# Substracting two values in same column in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I am a beginner in spotfire. I need to make a calculated column from the data shown below
[image]

The first column is a list of schools, the second column is the list of ranks students got in an exam and the third is the Score/Mark the particular student got.  I need to create a calculated column such that corresponding to every 4 th rank rank of each school I need to see the difference in Score obtained by Rank1 and Rank4 in the same  school. I am attaching the desired result below

[image]

I think the slution is to use some variant of OVER , but I am not able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

@user7266220 - The below expression should get you the desired result.

```
(If([Rank]=4,[Mark])) - Sum([Mark]) over (Intersect(firstnode([Rank]),[School]))
```

[image]

This works irrespective of rank order.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you are looking for

```
If(([Rank]=1) or ([Rank]=4),[Mark] - Max([Mark]) OVER (Intersect([School],Previous([Rank]))))
```

[image: Results]